# Why notify script sent me an email which tell me that the transaction is invalid?

Tags: php, paypal

I've made a script for a payment by paypal and i checked by sending emails if the informations are correct.

The notify script said that the transaction is incorrect.

I want to knw why . Thanks

```
 <?php
/* Script de Instant Payment Notification (IPN) ou Notification Instantanee de Paiement par Paypal */
/* Envoie un e-mail au vendeur quand Paypal a recu un paiement. Si la transaction est OK, Paypal se connecte a ce script et envoie des données, puis le script envoie un e-mail recapitulatif au vendeur.*/
/* Ajoutez l'URL de ce script lors de la creation d'un bouton Paypal ou dans les preferences de son compte Paypal a: Préférences de Notification instantanée de paiement. */
/* Derniere mise a jour: 15-02-2014 */

/* ADRESSE E-MAIL DU VENDEUR */
$emailto = "brian.millot@live.fr";
/* ADRESSE E-MAIL DE L'EMETTEUR DE CE MAIL (le FROM), DOIT ETRE UN VRAI COMPTE MAIL. */
$emailfrom = "brian.millot@gmail.com";
/* PREFIX AU SUJET DU MAIL POUR FILTRE ANTI-SPAM */
$sujetprefix = "[PAYPAL]";
/* CARACTERE SET DE VOTRE SITE WEB, METTRE utf-8 OU iso-8859-1 POUR BIEN AFFICHER LES CARACTERES ACCENTUES */
$charset = "utf-8";

/* NE RIEN MODIFIER CI-DESSOUS */

// lecture du post de PayPal et ajout de 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = trim(urlencode(stripslashes($value)));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// reponse a PayPal pour validation
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:80\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_name1 = $_POST['item_name1'];
$item_name2 = $_POST['item_name2'];
$item_name3 = $_POST['item_name3'];
$item_name4 = $_POST['item_name4'];
$item_name5 = $_POST['item_name5'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$item_number1 = $_POST['item_number1'];
$item_number2 = $_POST['item_number2'];
$item_number3 = $_POST['item_number3'];
$item_number4 = $_POST['item_number4'];
$item_number5 = $_POST['item_number5'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$quantity1 = $_POST['quantity1'];
$quantity2 = $_POST['quantity2'];
$quantity3 = $_POST['quantity3'];
$quantity4 = $_POST['quantity4'];
$quantity5 = $_POST['quantity5'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_name = $_POST['address_name'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// Envoi du mail
$mail_To = $emailto;
$mail_Subject = $sujetprefix . " Paiement PAYPAL validé et verifié";
$entetes  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
$entetes .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \n";
$entetes .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=".$charset."\n";
$entetes .= "Reply-To: ".$emailfrom."\n";
$entetes .= "From: ".$emailfrom."\n"; 

$mail_Body = "Paypal vient de valider et recevoir un paiement par carte bancaire. \nConnectez-vous à votre compte Paypal pour connaitre les détails de cette transaction et virer la somme sur votre compte. \nhttps://www.paypal.com/fr/";
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n====================================================";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Voici quelques informations sur la transaction:\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Transaction ID: " .  $txn_id ;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Date de paiement: " . $payment_date;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Etat du paiement: " . $payment_status;
$mail_Body .= "\n====================================================";
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Attention, les informations ci-dessous peuvent être incomplètes.";
$mail_Body .= "\n====================================================";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Nombre d'objets dans le panier: " . $num_cart_items;
if (strlen($item_name) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity; }
if (strlen($item_name1) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name1 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number1 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity1; }
if (strlen($item_name2) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name2 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number2 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity2; }
if (strlen($item_name3) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name3 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number3 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity3; }
if (strlen($item_name4) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name4 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number4 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity4; }
if (strlen($item_name5) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name5 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number5 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity5; }
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Facture numéro: " . $invoice;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Montant: " . $mc_gross . " " .$mc_currency;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Frais Paypal: " . $mc_fee . " " .$mc_currency;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Montant sur le compte: " . ($mc_gross - $mc_fee) . " " .$mc_currency;
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Nom: " . $first_name . " " .$last_name;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Rue: " . $address_street;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Code postal: " . $address_zip;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Ville: " . $address_city;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Etat et Pays: " . $address_state . " " .$address_country . " " .$address_country_code;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Adresse e-mail: " . $payer_email;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Nom de l'entreprise: " . $payer_business_name;
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Message du client: " . $memo;
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Statut Paypal du client: " . $payer_status;
$mail_Body .= "\n====================================================";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n";
}
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body . "\n\nVoici les données brutes reçues par Paypal: \n\n" . $emailtext, $entetes);
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

// Envoi d'un mail si invalide
$mail_To = $emailto;
$mail_Subject = $sujetprefix . " Paiement PAYPAL NON VALIDE";
$entetes  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
$entetes .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit \n";
$entetes .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=".$charset."\n";
$entetes .= "Reply-To: ".$emailfrom."\n";
$entetes .= "From: ".$emailfrom."\n"; 

$mail_Body = "Un client a voulu payer par Paypal mais la transaction n'est pas valide. La commande est annulée. \nCe message est envoyé pour information, il n'y a rien à faire. \nhttps://www.paypal.com/fr/ \nCi-dessous, les données brutes envoyées par Paypal.";
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n====================================================";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Nombre d'objets dans le panier: " . $num_cart_items;
if (strlen($item_name) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity; }
if (strlen($item_name1) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name1 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number1 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity1; }
if (strlen($item_name2) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name2 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number2 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity2; }
if (strlen($item_name3) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name3 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number3 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity3; }
if (strlen($item_name4) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name4 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number4 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity4; }
if (strlen($item_name5) > 1) { $mail_Body .= "\n\n" . "Objet en commande: " . $item_name5 . "\n" . "Numéro de l'objet: " . $item_number5 . " - " . "Quantité: " . $quantity5; }
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Facture numéro: " . $invoice;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Montant: " . $mc_gross . " " .$mc_currency;
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Nom: " . $first_name . " " .$last_name;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Rue: " . $address_street;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Code postal: " . $address_zip;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Ville: " . $address_city;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Etat et Pays: " . $address_state . " " .$address_country . " " .$address_country_code;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Adresse e-mail: " . $payer_email;
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Nom de l'entreprise: " . $payer_business_name;
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Message du client: " . $memo;
$mail_Body .= "\n";
$mail_Body .= "\n" . "Statut Paypal du client: " . $payer_status;
$mail_Body .= "\n===================================================="; 
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n";
}
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body . "\n\nVoici les données brutes reçues par Paypal: \n\n" . $emailtext, $entetes);
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

In suscribe.php when i click on the paypal buy button.

```
<?php
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$uid = $_SESSSION['user_id'];
if (array_key_exists($duration, $suscribe['prices']))
{
$price = $suscribe['prices'][$duration];
$custom = "action=suscribe&uid=$uid&duration=$duration";
$request = array(
'METHOD'=>'BMCreateButton',
'VERSION'=>'87',
'USER'    => $paypal['USER'],
'PWD'=> $paypal['PWD'],
'SIGNATURE'=> $paypal['SIGNATURE'],
'BUTTONCODE'=>'HOSTED',
'BUTTONTYPE'=>'BUYNOW',
'BUTTONSUBTYPE'=>'SERVICES',
'L_BUTTONVAR0'  => 'business='.$paypal['mail'],
'L_BUTTONVAR1'  => "item_name=Compte premium $duration mois",
'L_BUTTONVAR2'  => "amount=$price",
'L_BUTTONVAR3'  => "currency_code=EUR",
'L_BUTTONVAR4'  => "no_note=1",
'L_BUTTONVAR5'  => 'notify_url=http://www.project-heberg.fr/CREAZ/autozoom/abonnement/paypal.php',
'L_BUTTONVAR6'  => 'return=http://www.project-heberg.fr/CREAZ/autozoom/abonnement/index.php',
'L_BUTTONVAR7'  => 'cancel=http://www.project-heberg.fr/CREAZ/autozoom/abonnement/index.php',
'L_BUTTONVAR8'  => "custom=$custom",
);
?>
```

So i'm in this part because i recieved a mail which is writen that the transaction is invalide.

```
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
```

The mail with the variable .

```
Un client a voulu payer par Paypal mais la transaction n'est pas valide. La commande est annulée. 
Ce message est envoyé pour information, il n'y a rien à faire. 
https://www.paypal.com/fr/
Ci-dessous, les données brutes envoyées par Paypal.

====================================================
Nombre d'objets dans le panier: 

Objet en commande: Compte premium 1 mois Numéro de l'objet:  - Quantité: 1

Facture numéro: 
Montant: 10.00 EUR

Nom: Brian Millot
Rue: Av. de la Pelouse, 87648672 Mayet
Code postal: 75002
Ville: Paris
Etat et Pays: Alsace France
Adresse e-mail: buyer1@project-heberg.fr Nom de l'entreprise: 

Message du client: 

Statut Paypal du client: unverified
====================================================

Voici les données brutes reçues par Paypal: 

handling_amount = 0.00
discount = 0.00
insurance_amount = 0.00
payer_id = UJWQLPE3SGQ2Y
address_country_code = FR
btn_id = 2931501
ipn_track_id = 6bd61d0277852
address_zip = 75002
shipping = 0.00
charset = windows-1252
payment_gross =
address_status = unconfirmed
shipping_discount = 0.00
address_street = Av. de la Pelouse, 87648672 Mayet verify_sign = AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAYLu4Kmp.vAxQbTMLAxSCtrMd8Ho
item_name = Compte premium 1 mois
test_ipn = 1
txn_type = web_accept
receiver_id = 93DY87QLRTDX4
payment_fee =
mc_currency = EUR
transaction_subject = action=suscribe&uid=&duration=1 shipping_method = Default custom = action=suscribe&uid=&duration=1 protection_eligibility = Eligible address_country = France payer_status = unverified first_name = Brian address_name = Brian Millot mc_gross = 10.00 payment_date = 07:03:08 Apr 04, 2014 PDT payment_status = Completed quantity = 1 business = seller@project-heberg.fr item_number = last_name = Millot address_state = Alsace txn_id = 004406215Y2141340 mc_fee = 0.59 resend = true payment_type = instant notify_version = 3.7 payer_email = buyer1@project-heberg.fr receiver_email = seller@project-heberg.fr address_city = Paris tax = 0.00 residence_country = FR
```

Comment: You are doing a LOT of pointless work. ALl of your fsock/header definition stuff can be replaced with just a FEW `curl` calls, and all of your email mime junk can be replaced with just a few lines of phpmailer/swiftmailer code as well. Plus, you body is being built incorrectly, you're putting on a leading `&` which is incorrect.

Comment: @MarcB The code used is the default IPN script given by PayPal. It does not depend on the existence of a given extension such as cURL or PHPMailer.

Comment: I am sure this is something very simple, but the french is throwing me off and it's late.. sorry man, and good luck. Have you contact PayPal support?